# Using group by on two tables

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two tables. One is a subject and the other one is allocated subjects to students. What I need is to use GROUP BY and display all the students in a single column with all subjects.

Table: Subject_Selection

| SubjectID | Subject name |
| --- | --- |
| ITB001 | English |
| ITB002 | Urdu |
| ITB003 | Math |

Table: table Student with allocated subjects:

| Stdid | subject_id |
| --- | --- |
| stB001 | ITB001 |
| stB114 | ITB001 |
| stB114 | ITB002 |

The Final output I want to use GROUP BY:

| Student | Subject name |
| --- | --- |
| stB114 | English |
| stB114 | English,Urdu |

Comment: This is not a php question. Should remove the php tag

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got two product specific answers...)

Comment: I'm grateful that the solution you mentioned is indeed effective.

Comment: can we further categories it into nested HTML table like , I need to display the Subjects Name like where the Item AND Qty Listed in a Sub Table of HTML, here is the image attached you can check 
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlCpJfuYLzX6XxW8uDdgeQJRTciEJqal/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `inner join` to join data and `group by` with `group_concat` to combine data in single column :

```
select s.Stdid as Student, group_concat(Subject_name) as 'Subject name'
from Student s
inner join Subject_Selection ss on s.subject_id = ss.SubjectID
group by s.Stdid
```

Ps : this is a working solution for mysql/mariadb

If your are using an other dbms then you have to change `group_concat` by an equivalent.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/YEix92PJ)

Comment: I'm grateful that the solution you mentioned is indeed effective.

Comment: Glad to hear :), Can you accept my answer if you see it useful

Comment: Yes i Accept it

Comment: can we further categories it into nested HTML table like , I need to display the Subjects Name like where the Item AND Qty Listed in a Sub Table of HTML, here is the image attached you can check 
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlCpJfuYLzX6XxW8uDdgeQJRTciEJqal/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a complete different question, Maybe its an idea to Post it as new answer then someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1:-JOIN the 2 tables on subject_id so that you get student id and subject name and subject_id on a single tuple.

STEP 2:- just group by student_id and concat the different tuples in a particular group to a single tuple...

```
select Stdid as Student, group_concat(Subject_name) as 'Subject name' from Student NATURAL JOIN Subject_Selection group by Stdid;
```

DEMO:-
https://dbfiddle.uk/-YoftCWl

I used natural join since I changed the attribute name to SubjectID in both the tables; otherwise you can use inner join

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP which dbms this is for.

Comment: Also, your NATURAL JOIN is an INNER JOIN.

Comment: i had specified the DEMO, you can click and see which dbms engine this for. And it is NATURAL JOIN since i haven't specified any attributes explicitly upon which comparison will take place. Implicitly , the common attributes of both tables will be used.

Comment: by using group_concat it includes the , between the records But i want to use the html tags is there any way ?